# Highcharts: XAxis Labels Rotation weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, column-chart

Refer the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/9y3zs6ep/

```
labels: {
    rotation: 1
}
```

When I put rotation as 0, the labels are correctly aligned in horizontal position. But when I increase rotation to 1, the labels disappear, and as I increase angle, labels start appearing. How can I get correct alignment for these rotation values?

Comment: Set step parameter as 1. http://jsfiddle.net/yu50fr3j/

Comment: @SebastianBochan Thanks. But this seems to be a bug.

Comment: The value of `rotation` should be from 0 to 360 (the number of degrees in a circle). What do you want your labels to look like?